# How do I get count of a row in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner regarding SQL queries so I hope that someone can help me with this.

I have a table that has 2 columns that are called MID and jachtID.
What I need is the count of how many of the same jachtIDS there are with different MIDS attached to them like this:

```
MID   jachtID
89    10
95    10
83    11
```

The result should look something like this:

```
MID   jachtID  count
89    10       2
95    10       2
83    11       1
```

And I need this for all of the rows
I have tried using

```
  SELECT count(DISTINCT jachtID) FROM table
```

But this just gives me 1 big number and not the result that I need.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT 
    T.MID,
    T.jachtID,
    jT.total
FROM table T INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    jachtID,
    COUNT(*) total
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY jachtID
)AS jT

ON T.jachtID = jT.jachtID
```

---

First get `count` of each `jachtID` by the following query:

```
 SELECT 
   jachtID,
   COUNT(*) total
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY jachtID
```

Then make an `INNER JOIN` between the main table and the above query and get the corresponding `jatchtID` count thereby.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to do this with some `GROUP BY` magic, but I'm not sure, since you want all the rows. Using a sub query will work, though.

```
SELECT 
    a.MID, 
    a.jachtID,
    (SELECT count(b.jachtID) FROM table AS b WHERE b.jachtID= a.jachtID) AS `count` 
FROM table AS a
```